# Buttons are not perfectly equally as expected iOS Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to make "Two Equal-Width Buttons" As it's described in Apple Auto Layout Guide.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1

And it looks ok in preview of interface builder (Main.storyboard).But when I try to change devices i see that width is different on some devices.
How can i fix that ? How can I make equal width of buttons for all devices by using constraints or another techniques?

Updated Examples:

width is ok

[image: width is ok]

width is not ok

[image: width is not ok]

[Width is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQPSf.png)

[Width is not ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziFyJ.png)

Comment: Please specify your constraints

Comment: Can you update your images with the constraints visible?

Comment: Constraints size the same as in Auto Layout Guide:

1. Short Button.Leading = Superview.LeadingMargin

2.Long Button.Leading = Short Button.Trailing + Standard

3.Long Button.Trailing = Superview.TrailingMargin


4.Bottom Layout Guide.Top = Short Button.Bottom + 20.0

5.Bottom Layout Guide.Top = Long Button.Botton + 20.0


6.Short Button.Width = Long Button.Width

Comment: I updated screenshots. If you try the same example are you have the same width for all devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not problem with the width of your buttons. Because of difference of 0.5 point between two buttons, it may not be showing you equal width.

Just check width of both button manually, there may not be difference between them, more than 1 point.

Look at this snapshots:

#### iPhone 5

[image]

#### iPhone 8

[image]

#### iPhone X

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes. 
Is it considered as expected behaviour if the difference is no more than 1 point  ?
Does apple say that somewhere in documentation ? 
I thought the any different of size is wrong with no exceptions. I spent about more than one week to try fix that issue in my project.=)))

Comment: And what about X and Y for different devices?  Do they have the same rule as for the width - acceptable difference < 1 point?

Comment: @Val - This may be considered as bug of Apple. There is no specific rule for this, documented by Apple. I could be able explain you this issue becuase I had the same problem and there was no solution at all.

Answer (score 1):

Put your buttons inside a  `UIStackView` horizontal and set `distribution` attribute to `FILL EQUALLY`

Look this [tutorial](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/06/22/uistackview-distribution/) for more examples.

Comment: Ok,I will look at this. 
But I came from stack view to usual constraints because with the stack view i has the same issues despite of the same aspect ratio of buttons. The width has minor deference but it seems me wrong anyway.

Comment: Using `UIStackView` you dont need to put constraints in your buttons

Comment: I eventually needs to create a `UITabBar` "manually", and I always use a `UIStackView` to archieve this goal